# In Java, how does the GUI execute code on action event?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working with the Netbeans GUI builder, how does the following code work:

```
private void scanTagBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        XBeeDevice coordinator = new XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE);
         // do something
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
 XBeeDevice coordinator = new XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE);
  while(true) {
   // do something
  }
}
```

XBeeDevice represents my serial device.

I am wondering how the GUI can execute the action event when I have a infinite loop in my main program?? How does it work? I feel I am doing something very wrong

Comment: why you need actionEvent ? give more information

Comment: I am using the action event to check if the user wants to read data from the remote XBEE device @MR1

Comment: event handler works when an event is fire. it doesn't look is there a loop or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you realize an UI a thread is created. It is the Event Dispatcher Thread that is in charge of managing the dispatch of all events. Listener code is executed under the control of this thread.